# jQuery fadeOut one div, fadeIn another on its place

Tags: javascript, jquery, fadein, fade, fadeout

I'm trying a simple jQuery script to fadeout one div and fadein another one in it's place but for some reason the first div never fades out. It's probably an obvious problem with the code but I cannot seem to make it out.

```html
<style>
    #cuerpo { display: none; }
</style>

<div id="cuerpo"></div>
<div id="inicio"></div>

<script>
    function delayed() {
        $("div").fadeIn(3000, function () {
            $("cuerpo").fadeIn("slow");
        });
    }
    $("a").click(function () {
        $("inicio").fadeOut("slow");
        setTimeout("delayed()",500);
    });
</script>
```

How should I do it? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**UPDATE**

The simplest way to do this is by using a callback:

```
$('a').click(function(){
    $('#fadeout').fadeOut(300, function () {
         $('#fadein').fadeIn(300);
    });
});
```

then the HTML:

```
<a href="#">In/Out</a>

<div id="fadeout">Fade Out</div>
<div id="fadein" style="display:none;">Fade In</div>
```

OLD:

There is a simple way to do this:

```
$('a').click(function(){
    $('#fadeout').fadeOut(300);
    $('#fadein').delay(400).fadeIn(300);
});
```

Answer (score 4):

I think you can use callback...

```
$('#fadeout').fadeOut(300, function(){
                                      $("#fadein").fadeIn(300);
                                      });
```

this is the most stable way....

Answer (score 1):

There is a syntax error
it should be

```
$("#inicio").fadeOut("slow");
```

and not

```
$("inicio").fadeOut("slow");
```

Similarly

```
$("#cuerpo").fadeIn("slow");
```

and not

```
$("cuerpo").fadeIn("slow");
```

Comment: I fixed it through erasing all HTML inside inicio with javascript. However even after correcting the code the div id="inicio" kept reappearing. Don't know why. Would liked to write the code properly.