# Swap two divs with a same class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am sort-of stuck with this minor part and I can't move on with my project.
Basically what I am trying to do is to fadeIn/fadeOut between two divs with same class, but keep the function as short as possible.

I have made following but apparently it will work only if both divs are hidden in the begginging and I need to show default title (first div) on load and after 2 seconds I want to swap to another title and then it will keep going circular.

HTML:

```
<div class="ref-title">Sample Title #1</div>
<div class="ref-title">Sample Title #2</div>
```

JS:

```
function titleSwap () {
    $('.ref-title:hidden:first').fadeIn(500).delay(2000).fadeOut(500, function () {
        $(this).appendTo($(this).parent());
        titleSwap();
    });
} titleSwap();
```

CSS:

```
.ref-title {
    display: none;
}
```

[JS Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4xEUs/)

So I need first div displayed as block and then it will disappear and the other one will appear and keep going on like that... Any tips ?

Comment: Why did you use :hidden?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cZT62/1/) - Adding a hidden class to the div you want to start as hidden and then changing the function as below should work.

HTML

```
<div class="ref-title">Sample Title #1</div>
<div class="ref-title hidden">Sample Title #2</div>
```

CSS

```
.hidden {
    display: none;
}
```

JS

```
(function titleSwap() {
    $('.ref-title').not('.hidden').delay(2000).fadeOut(500, function () {
        var $me = $(this);
        $('.ref-title.hidden').removeClass('.hidden').hide().fadeIn(500, function () {
            $(this).removeClass('hidden');
            $me.addClass('hidden');
            titleSwap();
        });
    });
})();
```

Additionally, if you don't want to include the hidden class on the DIV within the mark-up you can just use `$('.ref-title:nth-child(2)').addClass('hidden');` before the `titleSwap` function to add the class to the second DIV.

Answer (score 1):

If you can use just show/hide you can try like this: [show/hide Example](http://jsfiddle.net/4xEUs/25/)

```
function toggleTitle() {
  $('header > h2').delay(2000).toggle('fast', function () {
    toggleTitle();
  });
}
```

If you must use fadeIn/fadeOut its a bit more complicated due to the concurrent fade effect between the titles... this is my solution [fadeIn/Out Example](http://jsfiddle.net/4xEUs/27/)

```
function toggleTitle() {
  var visible = $('header > h2:visible');
  var hidden  = $('header > h2:hidden');

  visible.delay(2000).fadeToggle('fast', function () {
    hidden.fadeToggle('fast');
    toggleTitle();
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

it's easy if you put ID's on them, is this posible? check out this answer 
[jQuery fadeOut one div, fadeIn another on its place](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6530626/jquery-fadeout-one-div-fadein-another-on-its-place)

```
$('#fadeout').fadeOut(300);
$('#fadein').delay(2000).fadeIn(300);
```

if you cannot add IDs, try this. it assumes they are the only elements under their immediate parent

```
$('.ref-title:first-child').fadeOut(300);
$('.ref-title:last-child').delay(2000).fadeIn(300);
```

Comment: He wants to keep the animation going, having the one visible fadeOut and the hidden one fadeIn every 2 seconds.